# Can't play hls on default WebView of react-native

Tags: android, webview, react-native, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to play an https live streaming video on my webview on react-native `import { WebView } from 'react-native';`

But the videos didn't isn't playing and I don't know why, when I use different browser (eg.. google chrome) it's playing at that browser on my mobile device, but when I use the webview of react-native, it didn't work

My webview code:

```
 <WebView
      source={{uri: `https://link to video that has a live streaming`}}
      // source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/'}}
      style={styles.webView}
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      useWebKit={true}
  />
```

I already tried the url on youtube and the videos there work on my webview, what should I do?
my device is android nougat.

Comment: For your info: Don't treat the WebVIew as a full-functional browser. Some features won't work there.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko uhm, what's the way for me to accomplish that? I use `WebChromeClient` on my previous created app on native android and it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm not trying to answer, because I am not good enough in video playback in Android, just wanted to leave a usefull note. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a little a late but, you can try with something like this.

```
const uri = "https://link to video that has a live streaming"
const html = `<video controls width="500" height="50">
            <source src="${uri}" type="application/x-mpegURL">
            </video>`;
return (
    <WebView
      allowsFullscreenVideo
      originWhitelist={["*"]}
      source={{ html }}
    />
```